# Sql query to get sales by day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello the below query gives the following output :

```
Sales     RestaurantID    Date
100.00      1             2016-01-01 
200.00      1             2016-01-02 
300.00      1             2016-01-03
```

Instead of that i need to convert the Date values to columns and show total sales under each day so the output should be like this

```
RestaurantID    2016-01-01  2016-01-02  2016-01-03     
1               100.00      200.00      300.00
```

**Query**

```
select sum(Sales),RestaurantID, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, Date)) as Date
from DailySales
group by dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, Date)),RestaurantID
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @pivcol varchar(max)
SELECT @pivcol = COALESCE(@pivcol + ',','') + '[' + date + ']'         
FROM  DailySales

exec('select * from DailySales 
pivot (sum(sales) for date in ('+ @pivcol +'))')
```

Comment: The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: we are not storing date in @pivcol we are storing string for in clause

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT *
FROM Table_3
PIVOT(SUM(Sales) 
FOR Date IN ([2016-01-01],[2016-01-02],[2016-01-03])) AS PVTTable
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]